# Missing argument 1 for PayPal_Adaptive in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I am using Angell EYE PayPal Adaptive Payments CodeIgniter Library. It give me an error in library paypal_adaptive

```
Missing argument 1 for PayPal_Adaptive::__construct()

Undefined variable: DataArray
```

I am adding all data in config file detail is below

```
        $config['Sandbox'] = TRUE;
    $config['APIVersion'] = '123.0';
    $config['APIUsername'] = $config['Sandbox'] ? 'paypaltest-facilitator_api1.gmail.com' : 'PRODUCTION_USERNAME_GOES_HERE';
    $config['APIPassword'] = $config['Sandbox'] ? 'JRGZPXDNRRL6LJNQE' : 'PRODUCTION_PASSWORD_GOES_HERE';
    $config['APISignature'] = $config['Sandbox'] ? 'AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A7uQi7GAsii.0uB9g5iAxqvN9Fzm' : 'PRODUCTION_SIGNATURE_GOES_HERE';
    $config['PayFlowUsername'] = $config['Sandbox'] ? 'SANDBOX_USERNAME_GOES_HERE' : 'PRODUCTION_USERNAME_GOGES_HERE';
    $config['PayFlowPassword'] = $config['Sandbox'] ? 'SANDBOX_PASSWORD_GOES_HERE' : 'PRODUCTION_PASSWORD_GOES_HERE';
    $config['PayFlowVendor'] = $config['Sandbox'] ? 'SANDBOX_VENDOR_GOES_HERE' : 'PRODUCTION_VENDOR_GOES_HERE';
    $config['PayFlowPartner'] = $config['Sandbox'] ? 'SANDBOX_PARTNER_GOES_HERE' : 'PRODUCTION_PARTNER_GOES_HERE';

    $config['ApplicationID'] = $config['Sandbox'] ? 'APP-80W284485P519543T' : 'PRODUCTION_APP_ID_GOES_HERE';
    $config['DeveloperEmailAccount'] = 'paypaltest-facilitator@gmail.com';
```

and now below is my library starting code that give an error about DataArray i don't know where this variable come from it is not written in any file......

```
    class PayPal_Adaptive extends PayPal_Pro
{
    var $DeveloperAccountEmail = '';
    var $XMLNamespace = '';
    var $ApplicationID = '';
    var $IPAddress = '';
    var $DetailLevel = '';
    var $ErrorLanguage = '';

    function __construct($DataArray)
    {
        parent::__construct($DataArray);
        $this->XMLNamespace = 'http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap';
        $this->IPAddress = isset($DataArray['IPAddress']) ? $DataArray['IPAddress'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $this->DetailLevel = isset($DataArray['DetailLevel']) ? $DataArray['DetailLevel'] : 'ReturnAll';
        $this->ErrorLanguage = isset($DataArray['ErrorLanguage']) ? $DataArray['ErrorLanguage'] : 'en_US';
        $this->APISubject = isset($DataArray['APISubject']) ? $DataArray['APISubject'] : '';
        $this->DeveloperAccountEmail = isset($DataArray['DeveloperAccountEmail']) ? $DataArray['DeveloperAccountEmail'] : '';
        exit;
```

and my controller code is below

```
        class Adaptive_payments extends CI_Controller 
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();

            // Load helpers
            $this->load->helper('url');

            // Load PayPal library
            $this->config->load('paypal');

            $this->load->library('paypal/Paypal_adaptive');
            $this->load->library('paypal/Paypal_payflow');
            $this->load->library('paypal/Paypal_pro');

            $config = array(
                'Sandbox' => $this->config->item('Sandbox'),            // Sandbox / testing mode option.
                'APIUsername' => $this->config->item('APIUsername'),    // PayPal API username of the API caller
                'APIPassword' => $this->config->item('APIPassword'),    // PayPal API password of the API caller
                'APISignature' => $this->config->item('APISignature'),  // PayPal API signature of the API caller
                'APISubject' => '',                                     // PayPal API subject (email address of 3rd party user that has granted API permission for your app)
                'APIVersion' => $this->config->item('APIVersion'),      // API version you'd like to use for your call.  You can set a default version in the class and leave this blank if you want.
                'ApplicationID' => $this->config->item('ApplicationID'), 
                'DeveloperEmailAccount' => $this->config->item('DeveloperEmailAccount')
            );

            if($config['Sandbox'])
            {
                error_reporting(E_ALL);
                ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 
            }

            $this->load->library('paypal/Paypal_adaptive', $config);    
        }


        function index()
        {
            $this->load->view('paypal/samples/adaptive_payments');
        }
```

Tell me how to slove this problem...

Comment: Provide `$DataArray` to library when library is used in code.

Comment: i already do that but not working...

Comment: Edit your question and show controller code of how you use library and how you pass `$DataArray`.

Comment: question updated...

Comment: You are loading library twice in constructor. First time without parameters (where error occures) and second time you are passing some array to library. Do you see it? You should load one library just once.

Comment: Where in controller?

Comment: Yes. In code you posted you have same library loaded twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, you seem to be loading all of the libraries without the $config array included as the second parameter.  Then you're setting $config and loading the adaptive library again.  Remove the loading of libraries without $config and it should work for you.  Try this for your controller:

```
    class Adaptive_payments extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // Load helpers
        $this->load->helper('url');

        // Load PayPal library
        $this->config->load('paypal');

        $config = array(
            'Sandbox' => $this->config->item('Sandbox'),            // Sandbox / testing mode option.
            'APIUsername' => $this->config->item('APIUsername'),    // PayPal API username of the API caller
            'APIPassword' => $this->config->item('APIPassword'),    // PayPal API password of the API caller
            'APISignature' => $this->config->item('APISignature'),  // PayPal API signature of the API caller
            'APISubject' => '',                                     // PayPal API subject (email address of 3rd party user that has granted API permission for your app)
            'APIVersion' => $this->config->item('APIVersion'),      // API version you'd like to use for your call.  You can set a default version in the class and leave this blank if you want.
            'ApplicationID' => $this->config->item('ApplicationID'), 
            'DeveloperEmailAccount' => $this->config->item('DeveloperEmailAccount')
        );

        if($config['Sandbox'])
        {
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 
        }

        $this->load->library('paypal/Paypal_adaptive', $config);    
    }


    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('paypal/samples/adaptive_payments');
    }
```